# Match in whole string with punctuation (issues using \b)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Usually to match complete words we use `\b` as word delimiter, but when we are dealing with a compound world including punctuation, this method does not work quite well. For instance, suppose the following string:

```
basic school co-operative limited
```

If we apply the following regex we get `co-operative` and `limited` as expected. This happens due to the order in the alternators:

```
\b(co-operative|co|co.|limited)\b
```

What happens if I do not have any control over the order of regex alternators and I get the following regex?

```
\b(co|co.|co-operative|limited)\b
```

In this scenario, just `co limited` would match instead of `co-operative limited`. Do we have any way to solve the problem in the order in the alternations?

Thanks for your priceless help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match complete words, you could change the `\b` assertion at the end of the regex to a positive lookahead for whitespace or the end of the string e.g.

```
\b(co|co.|co-operative|limited)(?=\s|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/htN1lh/1)

If you wanted to allow for certain punctuation after a word, you could add that into the lookahead, e.g.

```
\b(co|co.|co-operative|limited)(?=[\s.]|$)
```

Comment: Of course @Nick :) Thanks a lot. Very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the alternation with using a ?-quantifier to capture the longest version, if possible:

```
\b(co(-operative)?.?|limited)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/1D6BsU/1

unfortunately, this will also match "co-operatives," so we can be a bit more explicit to avoid that edge case:

```
\b(co(-operative(?=\b))?.?|limited)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/1D6BsU/2